# BB10 Cascades ListView is jittering / shaking

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am working on a chat application for BlackBerry that leverages `ListView` to display chat messages. I have different kinds of messages and therefore I use multiple `ListItemComponent`s, but what's more important, I use property: `stickToEdgePolicy: ListViewStickToEdgePolicy.End` to ensure that the scroll is positioned at the end when new chat messages arrive.

Everything is working fine, but sometimes the content of `ListView` starts shaking by few pixels up and down and that lasts infinitely. This is usually happening when a user is scrolling the view by swipe gestures and reaches the bottom. Also, this may happen if a new message has arrived. However, this never happens consistently! Also, worth to mention this happens with equal probability on square screen and rectangle screen devices.

While researching this, I found that the height of the view is affecting this jittering effect by making it less or more likely to happen, but none of the height values made it completely gone.

My question is addresed to the experienced BB10 developers, who practically saw this issue and know how to this fix.

The layout is pretty straightforward:

```
Container {
    ChatTitle {
       // this is just another Container with chat title Label
    }

    ListView {
        id: chatEntries
        stickToEdgePolicy: ListViewStickToEdgePolicy.End
        topMargin: ui.sdu(1)
        bottomMargin: ui.sdu(1)
        ...
        listItemComponents: [
            ...
        ]
    }
    ...
    // few controls below the ListView, e.g. TextArea, Buttons.
}
```

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: I had similar problem with listview and flickable with Qt 5.0. It was OK with 5.0.1. I filed a bug report, but they couldn't pinpoint the cause of the problem. So update Qt.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm married with vanilla Cascades (Qt 4.8), so I cannot update Qt.

Comment: Never came accross this problem, but I can ask other devs if they have